# Normalization for time series comparison

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, normalization, markov-process

I have a time series Markov Switching model, which is estimated in about 15 different versions. One or two of the time series had to be normalized in order to converge. That is 1-2 out of 15. My question is if I have to normalize all models in order to be able to compare and derive conclusions on the model's combination. For example, common pattern /behavior or is it fine to just normalize the non converging series but make sure it stated that results for them should be seen under the normalization.
How much will I loose from the normalize - non normalize series?
What are the best practices here?